# Query for Unique Documents from array of objects in mongo DB collection

Tags: mongodb

I need a query to remove duplicate documents from "A" collection . Once duplicates are removed then I shall create an index on "A" collection.

The "A" collection has almost 132920 documents.

Please find the "A" Collection Mongo DB Document Structure,

```
/*1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0aa7"),
        "aC" : "AB",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000002001",
        "aT" : "CA",
        "bID" : NumberLong(0),
        "pD" : "2019-06-18",
        "transactions" : [ 
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            }, 
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 3,
                "tC" : "S"
            }
        ]
    }

/*2*/
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0aa8"),
        "aC" : "AB",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000002002",
        "aT" : "CA",
        "bID" : NumberLong(0),
        "pD" : "2019-06-18",
        "transactions" : [ 
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            }, 
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 3,
                "tC" : "S"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
/*1*/
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0aa7"),
        "aC" : "AB",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000002001",
        "aT" : "CA",
        "bID" : NumberLong(0),
        "pD" : "2019-06-18",
        "transactions" : [ 
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            }, 
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 3,
                "tC" : "S"
            }
        ]
    }

/*2*/
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0aa8"),
        "aC" : "AB",
        "aI" : "ABCD",
        "aN" : "000000002002",
        "aT" : "CA",
        "bID" : NumberLong(0),
        "pD" : "2019-06-18",
        "transactions" : [ 
            {
                "seqNo" : 1,
                "tC" : "S"
            }, 
            {
                "seqNo" : 2,
                "tC" : "S"
            },
            {
                "seqNo" : 3,
                "tC" : "S"
            }
        ]
    }
```

After the duplicates are deleted from "transactions array". I shall create my primary index on "A" Collection as follows,

```
{
"aC" : 1.0,
"aI" : 1.0,
"aN" : 1.0,
"aT" : 1.0,
"bID" : 1.0,
"pD" : 1.0
```

}

Could you please help me out to remove duplicates documents from "A" collection so that I can enable Index on "A" collection?

Need help on the query .

Thanks in advance. It will be very helpful.

Comment: So, you just want to `update` collection `A` by removing duplicate objects from `"transactions"` array? ... Or?

Comment: yes @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "transactions": {"$type": "array"}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "transactions": {"$setUnion": "$transactions"}
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/72KUBAzBOWT).

**EDIT**

I don't know if it's a mongoplayground.net or MongoDB "oddity"/bug, but I suspect that something "reorders" the fields in the `"transactions"` array objects.

Here's a "workaround" that rewrites each element before the `"$setUnion"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "transactions": {"$type": "array"}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "transactions": {
        "$setUnion": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$transactions",
            "as": "xaction",
            "in": {
              "seqNo": "$$xaction.seqNo",
              "tC": "$$xaction.tC"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/596CWCJv8zL).

Comment: hi @richg12hs, Thanks for the reply. but i could see we still have duplicate when run in playground.    this is response i got when run,[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d654ed25616a9d461bc0aa7"),
    "aC": "AB",
    "aI": "ABCD",
    "aN": "000000002001",
    "aT": "CA",
    "bID": NumberLong(0),
    "pD": "2019-06-18",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "seqNo": 1,
        "tC": "S"
      },
      {
        "seqNo": 2,
        "tC": "S"
      },
      {
        "seqNo": 3,
        "tC": "S"
      },
      {
        "seqNo": 2,
        "tC": "S"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: @Shilpa  Strange, I'm not seeing any duplicates.  **EDIT** I pressed `run` several times AND sometimes there are duplicates.  mongoplayground.net or MongoDB bug?

Comment: @richg12hs i have modified my question in clear ...could you check once.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shilpa I don't know the root cause of the "strangeness", but I think there is a "workaround" to overcome it.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs, the ans has worked half way but i have multiple parameters other than seqNo and tC.how would i work with those rather than mentioning "in": {
              "seqNo": "$$xaction.seqNo",
              "tC": "$$xaction.tC"
            }

Comment: @Shilpa  You mean my answer fully worked for your half-asked question?  8-)  I did some testing on MongoDB Atlas and the first `update` in my answer above is consistent and correct for many runs.  Do you find that not to be so with your collection/server?  Currently I believe any issues are related to mongoplayground.net.